# How can I know number of support vectors in SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I want to compare number of support vectors in different SVM model. I have data for training/testing. I wan't to see how different are the numbers of support vectors in case of One vs One and One vs All methods. How can I know it?

Comment: `How should I calculate it?` In what sense? Like, you calculate the number of Support Vectors in both regimes and compare it. Without further clarifications this sounds unclear.

Comment: The time spent on one vs one is much less than one vs all both for training and testing of one feature. I want to see if the SV number is influencing it. Need exact numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important concept in SVM is $\alpha$, (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90767/113777) for details), the **lagrange multipliers**. For each data point $i$, there is associated $\alpha_i$. Most $\alpha_i$ will close to $0$, for non-zero ones, it is a support vector. Counting non-zero $\alpha$ is the way to go. Different software will have different implementations.

Here is a reproducible example in R.

```
library(mlbench)
library(kernlab)
set.seed(1)
d=mlbench.2dnormals(100,sd=0.5)

svp <- ksvm(d$x,d$classes,type="C-svc",kernel="polydot",
            prob.model=TRUE,kpar=list(degree=1, scale=1, offset=0))

plot(svp,data=x)
```

Here is the output for `svp`, and `length(svp@alpha[[1]])`. Note there are $6$ support vectors in this case (as plotted in the figure, $6$ solid black points), and the length of $\alpha$ is 6, since it contains only none-zero values.

```
> svp
Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
 parameter : cost C = 1 

Polynomial kernel function. 
 Hyperparameters : degree =  1  scale =  1  offset =  0 

Number of Support Vectors : 6 

Objective Function Value : -2.6809 
Training error : 0 
Probability model included. 
> svp@alpha
[[1]]
[1] 1.0000000 0.3360636 1.0000000 0.8088748 1.0000000 0.1449384
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using scikit-learn library in Python, you can use

```
clf.support_vectors_
```

where `clf` is your support vector classifier. More information on the attributes can be found [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html).